# Magento2: I wanted to save order details to my local database

Tags: magento2, sales-order, save

I wanted to `Save Orders` from `magento 2` to my local database or another database when new order is placed in Magento frontend.

I need to Save the order details when the `new order` is placed in `magento 2` OR is there any other alternative way to `save Orders` to a different database.

Please let me know what is the `ideal way` of `saving Orders` or Do I have to create a `module` and place a schedule `Cron` to check the new orders on `every 2 or 3 hours`.

Please help me to get started in right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your questions, the best practice would be to create a custom module and use the observer to catch every event of placing the order and write custom code or send the order details to an API. Consume the API and write the order details into another different database.

As you said another way to achieve this is to write a cron script to check the order table. If new entry comes in after the increment_id, you can add it to the separate database.

Alternatively, just for your information Magento commerce provides split database facility. You can find more information here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-master/multi-master.html

If you find my answer helpful, please upvote and accept it. Thank you.